# add sections and notes from sales orders in delivery note odoo 15

Tags: odoo, odoo-15

we use sections and notes in sales orders in odoo 15 to structure and specify our sales orders. We managed to get these infos displayed also on invoices.
Now, we would need them as well on delivery notes.
Is there a way to access these data from sales orders so that they are displayed and printed on delivery notes?

Since there is no reaction to this post I tought it might be a workaround to use the template for the saleorder report and adapt ist, so that prices and taxes are hidden and the report could be used with sections and notes from sales orders.
I adapted my module, to use the same template that I use for the sales orders report.
I now get an Key error

```
KeyError: 'doc'
Template: 1257
Path: /t/t/t[1]
Node: <t t-set="doc" t-value="doc.with_context(lang=doc.partner_id.lang)"/>
```

Strange because the code inside the new report ns_report_saleorder_stock_picking is exactly the same as the working report ns_report_saleorder.
Here the code of the new report, that is loaded from my module without errors, but only when I try to print the report it throws the error.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<odoo>
 <record id="action_report_saleorder_stock_picking" model="ir.actions.report">
            <field name="name">Delivery note</field>
            <field name="model">sale.order</field>
            <field name="report_type">qweb-pdf</field>
            <field name="report_name">ns_layout.ns_report_saleorder_stock_picking</field>
            <field name="report_file">ns_layout.ns_report_saleorder_stock_picking</field>
            <field name="print_report_name">’delivery note from  ' %s% (sale.order))</field>
            <field name="binding_model_id" ref="model_sale_order"/>
            <field name="binding_type">report</field>
</record>


    <data>
    <template id="ns_report_saleorder_stock_picking" inherit_id="sale.report_saleorder_document"> 
      <xpath expr="//div[hasclass('page')]" position="replace">
        <div class="page" style="font-size:80%;">
          <div class="oe_structure" />
          <div class="row mt32 mb32" id="informations" style="margin: 10mm 0mm 15mm 0mm;">
            <div class="col-8">
              <h4 class="mb16">
                <t t-if="not (env.context.get('proforma', False) or is_pro_forma)">
                  <span t-if="doc.state not in ['draft','sent']">Auftrag:</span>
                  <span t-if="doc.state in ['draft','sent']">Angebot:</span>
                </t>
                <t t-if="env.context.get('proforma', False) or is_pro_forma">
                  <span>Pro-Forma Rechnung:</span>
                </t>
                <span t-field="doc.name" />
              </h4>
            </div>
            <div class="col-4" style="margin-left:1mm;">
              <table style="width: 100%;">
                <th />
                <tr>
                  <td t-if="not (env.context.get('proforma', False) or is_pro_forma)">
                    <span t-if="doc.state not in ['draft','sent']">Auftrag:</span>
                    <span t-if="doc.state in ['draft','sent']">Angebot:</span>
                  </td>
                  <td t-if="env.context.get('proforma', False) or is_pro_forma">
                    <span>Pro-Forma Rechnung:</span>
                  </td>
                  <td>
                    <span t-field="doc.name" />
                  </td>
                </tr>
                <tr t-if="doc.partner_id.id">
                  <td>Kunden-Nr.</td>
                  <td>
                    <span t-field="doc.partner_id.id" />
                  </td>
                </tr>
                <tr t-if="doc.date_order and doc.state not in ['draft','sent']">
                  <td>Datum</td>
                  <td>
                    <span t-field="doc.date_order" t-options="{'format': 'dd.MM.yyyy'}" />
                  </td>
                </tr>
                <tr t-if="doc.date_order and doc.state in ['draft','sent']">
                  <td>Datum</td>
                  <td>
                    <span t-field="doc.date_order" t-options="{&quot;widget&quot;: &quot;date&quot;}" />
                  </td>
                </tr>
                <tr t-if="doc.validity_date" name="expiration_date">
                  <td>Gültig bis</td>
                  <td>
                    <span t-field="doc.validity_date" />
                  </td>
                </tr>
                <tr t-if="doc.amount_total" style="font-weight:bold; border-bottom: 1px solid grey;">
                  <td>Total</td>
                  <td>
                    <span t-field="doc.amount_total" />
                  </td>
                </tr>
              </table>
            </div>
          </div>
        <!--  display field with extra x_saleorder_notes -->
          <div t-if="doc.x_saleorder_notes" style="margin: 5mm 0mm;">
            <span>
              <strong>Anmerkung</strong>
            </span>
          <p><span style="font-style:italic;" t-field="doc.x_saleorder_notes" /></p>
          </div>      
          <!-- Is there a discount on at least one line? -->
          <t t-set="display_discount" t-value="any(l.discount for l in doc.order_line)" />
          <table class="table table-sm o_main_table">
            <!-- In case we want to repeat the header, remove "display: table-row-group" -->
            <thead style="display: table-row-group">
              <tr>
                <th name="th_description" class="text-left">Position</th>
                <th name="th_quantity" class="text-right">Menge</th>
                <th name="th_priceunit" class="text-right">Preis/Einheit</th>
                <th name="th_discount" t-if="display_discount" class="text-right" groups="product.group_discount_per_so_line">
                  <span>Disc.%</span>
                </th>
                <th name="th_taxes" class="text-right">Steuer</th>
                <th name="th_subtotal" class="text-right">
                  <span groups="account.group_show_line_subtotals_tax_excluded">Total</span>
                  <span groups="account.group_show_line_subtotals_tax_included">Total Price</span>
                </th>
              </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody class="sale_tbody">
              <t t-set="current_subtotal" t-value="0" />
              <t t-foreach="doc.order_line" t-as="line">
                <t t-set="current_subtotal" t-value="current_subtotal + line.price_subtotal" groups="account.group_show_line_subtotals_tax_excluded" />
                <t t-set="current_subtotal" t-value="current_subtotal + line.price_total" groups="account.group_show_line_subtotals_tax_included" />
                <tr t-att-class="'bg-200 font-weight-bold o_line_section' if line.display_type == 'line_section' else 'font-italic o_line_note' if line.display_type == 'line_note' else ''">
                  <t t-if="not line.display_type">
                   <td name="td_name">       
                        <span style="white-space: pre-wrap;" t-esc ="line.name" />
                    </td>          
                    <td name="td_quantity" class="text-right">
                      <span t-field="line.product_uom_qty" />
            
                    </td>
                    <td name="td_priceunit" class="text-right">
                      <span t-field="line.price_unit" />
                    </td>
                    <td t-if="display_discount" class="text-right" groups="product.group_discount_per_so_line">
                      <span t-field="line.discount" />
                    </td>
                    <td name="td_taxes" class="text-right">
                      <span t-esc="', '.join(map(lambda x: (x.description or x.name), line.tax_id))" />
                    </td>
                    <td name="td_subtotal" class="text-right o_price_total">
                      <span t-field="line.price_subtotal" groups="account.group_show_line_subtotals_tax_excluded" />
                      <span t-field="line.price_total" groups="account.group_show_line_subtotals_tax_included" />
                    </td>
                  </t>
                  <t t-if="line.display_type == 'line_section'">
                    <td name="td_section_line" colspan="99">
                      <span t-field="line.name" />
                    </td>
                    <t t-set="current_section" t-value="line" />
                    <t t-set="current_subtotal" t-value="0" />
                  </t>
                <!-- Format line notes
                -->
                  <t t-if="line.display_type == 'line_note'">
                    <td name="td_note_line" colspan="99" style="font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-style: normal; font-weight: bold;">
                    <span t-field="line.name" />
                    </td>
                  </t>
                </tr>
                <t t-if="current_section and (line_last or doc.order_line[line_index+1].display_type == 'line_section')">
                  <tr class="is-subtotal text-right">
                    <td name="td_section_subtotal" colspan="99">
                      <strong class="mr16">Subtotal</strong>
                      <span t-esc="current_subtotal" t-options="{&quot;widget&quot;: &quot;monetary&quot;, &quot;display_currency&quot;: doc.pricelist_id.currency_id}" />
                    </td>
                  </tr>
                </t>
              </t>
            </tbody>
          </table>
          <div class="clearfix" name="so_total_summary">
            <div id="total" class="row" name="total">
              <div t-attf-class="#{'col-4' if report_type != 'html' else 'col-sm-7 col-md-6'} ml-auto">
                <table class="table table-sm">
                  <!-- Tax totals -->
                  <t t-set="tax_totals" t-value="json.loads(doc.tax_totals_json)" />
                  <t t-call="account.document_tax_totals" />
                </table>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div t-if="doc.signature" class="mt32 ml64 mr4" name="signature">
            <div class="offset-8">
              <strong>Signature</strong>
            </div>
            <div class="offset-8">
              <img t-att-src="image_data_uri(doc.signature)" style="max-height: 4cm; max-width: 8cm;" />
            </div>
            <div class="offset-8 text-center">
              <p t-field="doc.signed_by" />
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="oe_structure" />
          <div style="font-size:80%;">
            <p t-field="doc.note" />
            <p t-if="not is_html_empty(doc.payment_term_id.note)">
              <!--       <span t-field="doc.payment_term_id.note"/>  -->
            </p>
            <p id="fiscal_position_remark" t-if="doc.fiscal_position_id and not is_html_empty(doc.fiscal_position_id.sudo().note)">
              <strong>Fiscal Position Remark:</strong>
              <span t-field="doc.fiscal_position_id.sudo().note" />
            </p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </xpath>
    </template>
  </data>
</odoo>
```

Does someone has an idea how i can get rid of this error??

Answer (score 0):

You need to call report template like this

```xml
<record id="action_report_saleorder_stock_picking" model="ir.actions.report">
    <field name="name">Delivery note</field>
    <field name="model">sale.order</field>
    <field name="report_type">qweb-pdf</field>
    <field name="report_name">ns_layout.ns_report_saleorder_stock_picking_doc</field>
    <field name="report_file">ns_layout.ns_report_saleorder_stock_picking_doc</field>
    <field name="print_report_name">’delivery note from %s'% (object.name))</field>
    <field name="binding_model_id" ref="model_sale_order"/>
    <field name="binding_type">report</field>
</record>
```

New calling template

```xml
<template id="ns_report_saleorder_stock_picking_doc">
    <t t-call="web.html_container">
        <t t-foreach="docs" t-as="doc">
            <t t-call="ns_layout.ns_report_saleorder_stock_picking" t-lang="doc.partner_id.lang" />
        </t>
    </t>
</template>

<template id="ns_report_saleorder_stock_picking">

</template>
```

Comment: Please note, I am not sure what you exactly want but i just help you with syntax to call any custom report

Comment: @ Harsch I've tried Your code. All tree code snippets are in the same ns_report_saleorder_stock_picking.xml file inside the /reports folder of my module. I had to add a suplementary </template> to close the first `<template id="ns_report_saleorder_stock_picking_doc">`and I remarked, that there was a wrong sign ´instead of ' at the  <field name="print_report_name"> line. Now I've got it to work, so that I can adapt the new report, so that there are no prices and taxes displayed in the delivery note. Just to say. This is a dirty workaround, that omits all the logic behind the stock picking.

Comment: Hi @geom thanks for review code and point missing statement.

for to display  prices and taxes displayed and all sale document related information you can use doc object as before.

Answer (score 0):

Hi I've implemented the code from Harsch the following way:
Inside my module I created the /reports/ns_report_saleorder_stock_picking.xml file and the path is referenced in the **manifest**.py file.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<odoo>
    <record id="action_report_saleorder_stock_picking" model="ir.actions.report">
            <field name="name">Lieferschein</field>
            <field name="model">sale.order</field>
            <field name="report_type">qweb-pdf</field>
            <field name="report_name">ns.ns_report_saleorder_stock_picking_doc</field>
            <field name="report_file">ns.ns_report_saleorder_stock_picking_doc</field>
            <field name="print_report_name">('Lieferschein zu Auftrag '+object.name)</field>
            <field name="binding_model_id" ref="model_sale_order"/>
            <field name="binding_type">report</field>
    </record>

    <data>
    <template id="ns_report_saleorder_stock_picking_doc">
    <t t-call="web.html_container">
        <t t-foreach="docs" t-as="doc">
            <t t-call="ns.ns_report_saleorder_stock_picking" t-lang="doc.partner_id.lang"/>
        </t>
    </t>
    </template>
    
    
    <template id="ns_report_saleorder_stock_picking" inherit_id="sale.report_saleorder_document">
         <xpath expr="//div[hasclass('page')]" position="replace">

              <!-- Here adapted template without prices and taxes -->

         </xpath>
    </template>
  </data>
</odoo>
```

I get now a second option in the print menue to print the newly created 'Lieferschein' (delivery note) based on the 'ns_report_saleorder_stock_picking.xml' (without prices).

[image: newly created menue entry Lieferschein]

The problem is, that both menue options produce the same new report 'Lieferschein' (without prices).

[image: Lieferschein]

The original report 'Angebot / Auftrag' (with prices) which should be printed with the first menue option is omitted now. It is only printed, when I deactivate the new Lieferschein report again in the **manifest**.py file.

[image: Original sale order with prices and taxes]

How can I force odoo to assign the new report Lieferschein (without prices) only to the second menue entry, while leaving the first menue option (Angebot / Auftrag) as is with the original report (with prices and taxes)?